# How do I setup sendgrid mail in Github actions?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, github-actions

I'm trying to set up SendGrid in my Github actions. I am using SendGrid Action.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/peter-evans/sendgrid-action), I can use an alternative path like

```
- name: SendGrid
      uses: peter-evans/sendgrid-action@v1
      env:
        SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.SENDGRID_API_KEY }}
        SCRIPT_FILEPATH: ../src/helper/sendgrid/script.js
```

But each time I run the Github action I get this error `/entrypoint.sh: line 8: ../src/helper/sendgrid/script.js: not found`

Is there something I'm missing?

Update:
I changed the path to `./src/helper/sendgrid/script.js` and I'm getting a new error `/entrypoint.sh: line 8: ./src/helper/sendgrid/script.js: Permission denied`

Comment: Did you mean `./src/helper/sendgrid/script.js`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Permission denied` error is most likely because the script must be executable.
Give the script executable permission as follows.

```
chmod +x script.js
```

This point is mentioned in the [readme documentation](https://github.com/peter-evans/sendgrid-action).